# This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, fim

I have a phantom or orphaned server in my farm and I'm not sure how to remove the entry as the server is not joined to the farm any longer, although part of the farm seems to think it is.
In central administration Problems & Solutions the following 3 errors persist:

*This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems.*
and
*More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint.*

In both cases the failing server is the phantom server - spapp03

In addition to these Configuration errors there is an Availability error: *One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly.* This also points to the phantom server and to SPTimerV4

However when I log onto the current CA server, spapp01 and run get-CacheClusterHealth or Get-CacheHost, spapp03 does not show up in the list. I have only 1 WFE and 1 APP in the farm.

So this server is showing up in Problems & Solutions but not showing up when looking at the cache cluster. Any ideas on what I might do to insure the phantom server is fully forgotten by my SharePoint farm or how I can get  better idea of what's going on here?

User Profile Synch is also not starting up and no FIMCertificates are being created when trying to get it started.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to **recreate AppFabric cluster from scratch**.
First, save the Cache Cluster config:

```
Use-CacheCluster
Export-CacheClusterConfig -path C:\...\ClusterConfig.xml
```

And also registry settings (especially *ConnectionString*) at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Configuration`

Then try to just stop and remove DistributedCacheService in SP:
First, the "right" way at every server running Appfabric:

```
Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance -Graceful  
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

If something gone wrong, try to manually delete the service instances:

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService" 
$instances = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {$_.service.tostring() -eq $instanceName} 
foreach ($instance in $instances) {
    $instance.Unprovision() 
    $instance.Delete()
}
```

and then, try again:

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

By doing this, we have disabled Distributed Cache service from SP perspective.

Then, you can remove every host from cluster as from AppFabric perspective:

```
Use-CacheCluster
Stop-CacheHost
Unregister-CacheHost -HostName <Servername> -ProviderType SPDistributedCacheClusterProvider -ConnectionString <AsInRegistry>
```

If all hosts are removed, AppFabric cluster are not exist anymore.

At this point, make sure that on all your cache servers.

- *Distributed Cache service* is not present in SharePoint
- *AppFabric* Windows Service are in **Disabled** state
- *Get-CacheHost* returns empty list
- In registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Configuration` following keys *ServiceConfigured* and *AdminConfigured* are set to 0.

After that you can add your SharePoint servers to the new appfabric\DC cluster by running on servers you have chosen:

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

And check that all is **UP** and **ONLINE**

- from AppFabric side: `Get-CacheHost`
- and SharePoint side:

  ```
  Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq
  "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"}
  ```

Use this nice article from MS as reference (also contains Fine-Tune settings for SP): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service